# How to add a choice that AlertDialog message cannot show next time?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the page that will show the AlertDialog message everytime.

I want to add the choice (like checkbox) that user can check if they want to not show that message next time.

How can I do?

Comment: Like you said, get the value of the checkbox after the user does check it and save it to sharedpreferences. Next time round, just check the value stored and use it to determine whether to display the dialog or not

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a custom view for your dialog, having a check box.
2. Add a listener to your dialog and find out if the check-box was checked when the dialog is closed.
3. Put an entry in Shared Preferences, telling you that check box was checked once.
4. Whenever you want to show the dialog, only show it if you haven't saved that entry yet.